# When does the OS switch threads in a multithreaded program?

Tags: java, multithreading, theory

I noted that in the following Java program, the OS switches threads quite randomly.

This made me wonder: **why and when does the OS 'decide' to switch threads**?

For example, consider the following program:

```
class NewThread extends Thread {

    private String message;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NewThread threadOne = new NewThread("1");
        NewThread threadTwo = new NewThread("2");

        threadOne.start();
        threadTwo.start();
    }

    public NewThread(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doLoop(message);
    }

    public void doLoop(String message)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

For the output, I get a long series of `1`'s, and then at some point I get this:

```
1
1
1
2
1
2
2
2
2
2
```

Why does this happen? When does the OS switch threads?

According to my knowledge, `for loops` cannot run at the same time (at least not with single-core processors). This makes me wonder what triggers the OS to do so?

Comment: `run()` vs `start()`. Read the javadoc.

Comment: Sotirios speaks truth. Calling run does not actually start a new thread. Effectively you've just made a couple normal function calls that are going to execute and return in order, thus, never leaving the main execution thread. You'll just see ten thousand 1's followed by ten thousand 2's.

Comment: What @SotiriosDelimanolis says, plus 'when do threads switch automatically?' - 'never' would be my first answer.  The set of threads running on cores cannot change unless there is an interrupt to enter the OS, either a hardware interrupt from a peripheral device that runs a driver, or a software interrupt, (system call), from one of the currently-running threads.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis @captainroxors @MartinJames That was just a typo, I meant `start()` indeed. Please reconsider my question and see the update.

Comment: CPU doesn't start threads, the OS (or some mid level thread manager) does, usually preemptively and based on fairness or other metrics. The CPU just runs what it's told to, on any available core, sometimes on multiple HW threads (if supported).

Comment: @Leeor, thanks for the addition. I will change it directly.

Comment: If you want to ask about process/thread scheduling in the host operating system, well... the answer is "it depends."

Comment: @2rs2ts: It depends on what exactly?

Comment: An OS will use a scheduling protocol to determine what processes/threads should run at what times (and when to force a context switch). These are generally non-trivial decisions to make (since they are based on process priority, pipelining use of resources, and many other variables), and as a developer building on top of OS scheduling you should assume that you cannot know when a context switch will happen. This fact is a driving force behind race conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Thread Switchng

- **Why?**

  Each thread in alive state is supposed to run in parallel to each other (from the point of view of programmer). However, it is not practical as no of cores is limited. So as many threads as supported by your processor may run in parallel. In a quad core processor, your two threads would actually run in parallel, but 10 threads won't. In order to create the illusion of parallel execution, thread switching has to take place periodically.
- **When?**

  No one can answer that. It really depends upon the JRE implementation, underlying hardware capabilities and countless other factors (like load of other running softwares). The operating system also matters a lot in this case. It is considered to be unpredictable by programmers (we should never assume or rely on the order and switching time).
- **How to check?**

  The current method that you are using to check the order of execution is misguiding. Here, a shared object `System.out` is being used, and it is cached (hopefully) by each thread and the output will be synchronized with actual memory and io at an order irrespective of the actual order of execution. It might make sense on a single core processor, but only on some implementations.

---

We use java to get platform independence (mostly), and this is a highly unpredictable thing which is dependent on so many parameters that we can't even list. (If you make one, it'll be outdated by next java update (probably), and it will not be same for all platforms). So I'd suggest you to assume (as far as writing programs in java is concerned) that they'll be executed in parallel.

For academic purposes, it's really an interesting topic if you are going to search and research more about it. If you find something interesting let us know too. :)

Hope this helps..
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You're not using thread right now.
If you call yourThread.run(), you just call the method run...
What you need is to call yourThread.start(). This will start the Thread. The thread will execute itself the run method.

Comment: Just a comment, this will *noy* start the Thread, it will just call the run method as you mention.

Comment: @lpratlong: Please see the update of my question. It was a typo.

Comment: @prmottajr: Please see the update of my question. It was a typo.